# Unable to connect Azure purview from Azure Synapse

Tags: azure-synapse, azure-purview

I followed the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/catalog-and-governance/quickstart-connect-azure-purview)  for connecting azure purview account with synapse.
I do not see option - Manage -> Azure Purview in Synapse Workspace.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **UPDATE:** Azure Purview Integration is now available in Azure Synapse Studio.

[image]

---

On `January 8th, 2021`

> The integration between Azure Synapse Analytics and Azure Purview is currently under Preview. If you are interested to try Azure Purview in Synapse, please connect with your Microsoft Sales Representative.

To get access to this feature you need to reach out to your sales representative at Microsoft.

In case, if you do not have a sales representative at Microsoft. I would suggest you file a support ticket and with a strong business use case.

Once you have created a support ticket, I would request you to share the support request number so that I can route it to the Azure Synapse team to enable access to the Azure Purview.

Comment: Thanks Pradeep. Will check with sales contact.

Comment: Thanks, will test it out.

Comment: @CHEEKATLAPRADEEP-MSFT I have issues connecting purview and scanning sql on prem. Can access it though in ADF are you able to help. Happy to post question

Answer (score 0):

Hello as mentioned Pradeep, the integration feature is under gated preview but will be public very soon (end of January). In the meantime, if you still want to connect, please connect through my LinkedIn profile (Arnaud Comet).

Thank you,
Arnaud